# how to put component as a children in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three components . First one **FormTemplate** in which children come as a props.FormRender which have two props FormTemplate ,formSection.**I am trying to put formSection inside FormTemplate**. but it is not working

**current output**

```
Form Template
Form Template End
section
```

**Expected output**

```
Form Template 
section
Form Template End
```

can you please help how to achieve this

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-elbakyan-j429zl?file=/src/App.js:0-505

```
import "./styles.css";

function FormTemplate({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Form Template</div>
      <div>{children}</div>
      <div>Form Template End</div>
    </>
  );
}

function FormRender({ formTemplate, formSection }) {
  return (
    <>
      {formTemplate}
      {formSection}
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FormRender
        formTemplate={<FormTemplate />}
        formSection={<section>section</section>}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead pass the component definition:

```js
formTemplate={FormTemplate}
```

then, within your renderer, use the component as JSX. You need to ensure you give the component a capital letter so that React sees it as a custom component, which I've done below by [destructuring and providing a new variable name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) (`: FormTemplateComponent`):

```
function FormRender({ formTemplate: FormTemplateComponent, formSection }) {
  return (
    <FormTemplateComponent>
      {formSection}
    </FormTemplateComponent>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Render the `formSection` component as a child inside the `FormTemplateComponent`.

```
function FormRender({ formTemplate: FormTemplateComponent, formSection }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <FormTemplateComponent>
        {formSection}
      </FormTemplateComponent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Putting it together in the entire App:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function FormTemplate({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Form Template</div>
      <div>{children}</div>
      <div>Form Template End</div>
    </>
  );
}

function FormRender({ formTemplate: FormTemplateComponent, formSection }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <FormTemplateComponent>
        {formSection}
      </FormTemplateComponent>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FormRender
        formTemplate={FormTemplate}
        formSection={<section>section</section>}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```